# Passing User Attrinbutes from CAS to web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, saml, cas

I have a web app, that is protected by CAS. Now i want to print the current logged user but. I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException:No name matching localhost found
```

Here is my code

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getServletContext().log("T1");
    System.out.println("T2");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    String userID = request.getRemoteUser();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
    writer.println("<body>");
    writer.println("<h1>Congratulations! You are logged in " + userID + "</h1>");if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        AttributePrincipal principal = (AttributePrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();

        writer.println("<h1>P: " +  principal.getName() + "</h1>");


        Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();

        Iterator<String> attributeNames = attributes.keySet().iterator();

        writer.print("<p>");
        writer.println();

        while(attributeNames.hasNext()) {
            String attributeName = attributeNames.next();

            writer.print(attributeName + ": ");
            writer.print(attributes.get(attributeName));
            writer.println();
        }

        writer.print("<p>");
    }

    writer.println("<body>");
    writer.println("</html>");

    writer.close();         
}
```

In my web.xml I use the SAMLValidationFilter and SAMLAuthentication Filter correctly. Have anyone an idea what i'm doing false. Or hava a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the example code. It's your environment. You're trying to reach an HTTPS endpoint that is untrusted by your runtime java environment. Test that endpoint with https://github.com/UniconLabs/java-keystore-ssl-test